# go binary-only error cannot find package fmt (using -importcfg) cannot open file : open : no such file or directory

Tags: go

I'm having a problem related with go binary-only package. So I created a very simple go application. Here is the structure:

```sh
$ tree -L 2 $GOPATH/src/

/Users/megadestina/Documents/gopath/src/
├── lib
│   └── lib.go
└── ukulele
    └── main.go
```

The `lib` folder is library I wanted to distribute as binary only. Where the `ukulele` is the main package.

Below is the content of `lib/lib.go`:

```golang
package lib

import "fmt"

func SayHello() {
    fmt.Println("hello there")
}
```

I performed `go install` command on the `lib` package, and it's success.

```sh
$ go install -a
$ ls $GOPATH/pkg/darwin_amd64 | grep lib.a
lib.a
```

Then I edited the `lib/lib.go` into below:

```golang
//go:binary-only-package

package lib
```

On the main package file `ukulele/main.go`, the `lib` package is being consumed. Here is the code:

```golang
package main

import "lib"

func main() {
    lib.SayHello()
}
```

I run the application and got following error.

```sh
$ go run main.go 
# command-line-arguments
cannot find package fmt (using -importcfg)
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link: cannot open file : open : no such file or directory
```

What should I do to make it work, to make the `lib` package distributed as binary-only package?

---

Fyi, I use `go1.11.4`.

```sh
$ go version
go version go1.11.4 darwin/amd64
```

Here is the output of `go env`:

```sh
$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/megadestina/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/megadestina/Documents/gopath"
GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/3h/5t8llxf147j06h5jcmy0474r0000gp/T/go-build021065592=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

Comment: Starting with Go 1.13, binary-only packages are no longer supported.

Comment: @icza I use go1.11, but it is not working. any idea?

Comment: What is the output of `go env`?

Comment: just updated my question, please take a look